# Probability that one normal Random Variable will fall within a given range of another.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm struggling with the following problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9aou.png]
(ed: Don't be lazy.  Just type it out. )

> 1. A certain small freight elevator has a max. capacity $C$, which is Normally distributed, with mean $400\text{lbs.}$, and standard deviation $4\text{lbs.}$
>
>    The weight of the boxes being loaded into the elevator is a R.V., with mean $30\text{lbs.}$, and standard deviation $0.3\text{lbs.}$.
>
>    How many boxes may be loaded into this elevator before the probability of disaster exceeds $0.2$?
>
>    Consider the random variable, $C$, to be independent of the weight of the boxes.

I know that with a normal distribution, I'm going to want to standardize at least one of them.

I thought of using a Z table to look up Probability( $E \geq Z$ ), where:

$E$ is the sum of the weights of n boxes (so expected value of $E = (n)(30)$ )

$Z$ is the normalized random variable $C$ (so $Z = (C - 400)/16$ )

But I'm not sure how to find a numerical solution to this. If $E$ is not fixed, how can I lookup a probability in a table.

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The sum of independent normally distributed random variables is a normally distributed random variable with (1) its mean being the sum of the means, (2) its variance being the sum of the variances.

You want to find $n$ such that $\mathsf P((\sum_{k=1}^n B_k) - C \geq 0)\gt 0.2$, where $\{B_k\}$ are the weights of boxes and C is the capacity of the elevator; which are each normally distributed R.V., with the given means and variances.   (Note: do you remember what is the relation between variance and standard deviation?)

Then so too is $X \mathop{:=} (\sum_{k=1}^n B_k) - C$ a normally distributed random variable.   Find its mean and variance, then the probability it exceeds zero.   (Or rather, find what value of $n$ makes the probability $0.2$.)

$\Box$

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the mean (expected value) of X will be  (n)(30) - 400? As for the variance, do I sum them all as positive, ex (n)(0.3^2)  + (4^2), or do I take the difference, as with the mean? My intuition is to sum them both as positive.

Comment: As well, when I standardize the X in P( X >= 0 ), I must also standardize the zero. And if I do that, how can I find an answer? The LHS and RHS of the inequality will be unknown.